# Authentication and authorization Spark Thrift Server

Tags: authentication, authorization, spark-thriftserver

I am using HDP 2.5.0. I try to implement Spark Thrift Server authorization using tutorial:

[Apache Spark Fine Grain Security with LLAP Test Drive](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/72454/apache-spark-fine-grain-security-with-llap-test-dr.html)

It working correctly, when I using username to login (not have password) and execute HiveQL. But I cannot find any way to authenticate user before allowed to access authorization system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps worked for my SparkThriftServer Authentication:
https://mapr.com/docs/52/Hive/HiveServer2-CustomAuth.html